# Disk I/O error copying a Exchange 2007 database

Tags: exchange-2007

A short time ago due to disk space I moved our Exchange database onto an external drive, the drive was new and the database was being backed up daily. I've now discovered the database is corrupt, I've run the Exchange utils to fix the database and this works but it corrupts again as soon as I try to move it. I need to get it off the disk, any suggestions? I'm also trying to restore the last good database but I'd like try to get the database off this disk, any suggestions?

PS I know putting the db on an external disk was a bad move, I had no where else to put it :-(

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tired using Xcopy or robocopy to move it with the ignore errors switch set?  Not sure how it handles IO errors, but its worth a try.